# How to plot graphs in Gnuplot in Real time in C++?

Tags: c++, real-time, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a graph in real time using GNUplot and C++.
Does anyone know of any good libraries that does this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gnuplot supports input via pipes (on windows, there's a separate executable for this, `pgnuplot`).  Then your program can send new commands to gnuplot, such as `replot`, just as if you were typing them into the gnuplot interface directly.

How you set up the pipe connection and write to the sending end of the pipe from your C++ program varies by operating system, so you'll have to tell us what you're using if you want more help.

On Windows, there's `CreatePipe` and then you set the `hStdInput` element of the `STARTUPINFO` struct you pass to `CreateProcess`.  Ditto with `hStdOutput` if you need the status messages from `pgnuplot`.

On POSIX (Unix, Linux, Mac OSX, etc), you can just use `popen` as the quick way to get a unidirectional connection.  For bidirectional, it works more like on Windows: `pipe` to get handles to the ends, then `fork` and in the child process call `dup2` to associate stdin and stdout with the pipe, then `exec` to have `gnuplot` replace the child process, keeping the pipes you set up.

EDIT: From [the gnuplot documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf):

> The special filename **’-’** specifies
>   that the data are inline; i.e., they
>   follow the command. Only the data
>   follow the command; **plot** options like
>   filters, titles, and line styles
>   remain on the **plot** command line. This
>   is similar to << in unix shell script,
>   and $DECK in VMS DCL. The data are
>   entered as though they are being read
>   from a file, one data point per
>   record. The letter "e" at the start of
>   the first column terminates data
>   entry. The **using** option can be applied
>   to these data — using it to filter
>   them through a function might make
>   sense, but selecting columns probably
>   doesn’t!

Comment: I figured that, but what are the commands to send individual points? I only know how to tell it to plot a data file, or a function. How do I plot like x1 y1, x2 y2, point by point?

Comment: @chutsu: I didn't provide those details because you said you already knew the gnuplot part.  Anyway, added the relevant paragraph from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [gnuplot interfaces in ANSI C](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/)?, this is an interface for C but in the same links there are some interface for C++.  Or you could try [PlPlot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in soft-realtime plotting, you're probably best of using a hardware accelerated graphics api (such as OpenGL), and plotting the chart yourself.

Comment: Am really hoping to use gnuplot, cause that is what I ready know, I have seen various interfaces that streams real data into gnuplot using perl, but because this is an assignment for my uni course, the course director really wants me to do it in C++.

Comment: Define what "realtime" means for you. If it means "25 updates per second", then gnuplot is probably not for you.

Comment: 1 plot a second is plenty for me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://search.cpan.org/~dkogan/feedGnuplot-1.08/bin/feedGnuplot This is a commandline utility, but also works well if controlled from a program.

Comment: Also available in HomeBrew for Mac OS - brew install feedgnuplot

Answer (score 0):

In my C++ code, this worked (on mac OsX mavericks, using g++ Apple LLVM version 5.0):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

// ready to make a plot

pid_t childpid=fork();
if(childpid==0) {
  // child process makes plot
  std::FILE* pipehandle=popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
  // make some plot. You can send multiple commands to the pipe each ending in \n
  std::fprintf(pipehandle,"plot \"results.txt\" using 1:2 with lines\n");
  std::fprintf(pipehandle,"quit\n");
  std::fflush(pipehandle);
  std::fclose(pipehandle);
  // child process exits
  exit(0);
}
// parent process waits for child process to exit
waitpid(childpid,NULL,0);

// you can now repeat to make other gnuplots; all will appear simultaneously in the 
// terminal and are persistent after the parent process has finished.
```

Comment: This should be possible without having to open external gnuplot application - any change you know how to do that in Windows - I know this is done via. fx. sigpack on ubuntu