# Create EPS from vectors, C++

Tags: c++, plot, eps

I have some C++ code that creates two vectors of double x,y as the results of my simulations.

At the moment I save x and y into a .txt file and import these values into Matlab for plotting and saving the figure as eps.

How can I generate and save my plots directly from C++?

I don't want to interface Matlab and C++ for this, but rather using C++ libraries.

Comment: If you can use GNUplot, then it can be done this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445720/how-to-plot-graphs-in-gnuplot-in-real-time-in-c. Also here is a library for that: http://www.suiri.tsukuba.ac.jp/~asanuma/gnuplot++/. The second link infact provides some handy examples as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GNUplot for this purpose of plotting your data. There is a handy library here: http://www.suiri.tsukuba.ac.jp/~asanuma/gnuplot++/ which can give you API's that can be called from your program to plot your data using GNUplot.